# Tensorflow error: Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Im currently trying to train a categorical model in keras and I'm getting stumped by this error.

This is my code I have so far:

```
predictors=["Body Mass (g)", "Flipper Length (mm)", "Culmen Depth (mm)", "Culmen Length (mm)", "Stage", "Island", "Region"]
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test =train_test_split(db[predictors], db["Species"], test_size=.2)
x_train= x_train.to_numpy()
x_test = x_test.to_numpy()
y_train = y_train.to_numpy()
y_test = y_test.to_numpy()

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(7,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(46, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy'], 
    run_eagerly=True)

history = model.fit(partial_x_train,
                    partial_y_train,
                    epochs=20,
                    batch_size=512,
                    validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

Note: I have tried both with and without run_eagerly. I'm not sure what else I could be missing.

```
Tensorflow error: Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)
```

Edit:
Here is the shape of partial_x_train:

```
x_val = x_train[:1000]
partial_x_train = x_train[1000:]
y_val = y_train[:1000]
partial_y_train = y_train[1000:]
```

Comment: What are the shapes of `partial_x_train` and `partial_y_train`? Include them in the question as well.

Comment: @Shubham Panchal 
```
x_val = x_train[:1000]
partial_x_train = x_train[1000:]
y_val = y_train[:1000]
partial_y_train = y_train[1000:]
```

Comment: I meant to say, what's the output of `partial_x_train.shape` and `partial_y_train.shape`?

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal partial_x_train is (0,7) and partial_y_train is (0,)

Comment: As the shapes are `( 0 , 7 )` and `( 0 , )`, the arrays aren't holding any samples and hence you're getting the error. Make sure that you are loading the data correctly.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal Oh ok, I was able to fix that just now but now I am getting this error

Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float).

Comment: Please try again by converting x_train, y_train, x_test and y_test as `'x_train=np.array(x_train, dtype='float32')'`.